# python regex get first part of an email address

Tags: python, regex

I am quite new to python and regex and I was wondering how to extract the first part of an email address upto the domain name. So for example if:

```
s='xjhgjg876896@domain.com'
```

I would like the regex result to be (taking into account all "sorts" of email ids i.e including numbers etc..):

```
xjhgjg876896
```

I get the idea of regex - as in I know I need to scan till "@" and then store the result - but I am unsure how to implement this in python.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you _need_ to use regex for this (e.g., as part of a homework assignment or something)? Or are you just guessing that there's no other way to do this?

Comment: If you _do_ need to use a regex, you will have to read a tutorial on them, and on the Python `re` module. If I just said "Use `re.match('^(.*?)@', s)`", you wouldn't know how to use the thing that comes back, how to debug or extend it, etc., so what you be the point?

Comment: Do you also want to parse these valid email addresses: `Tony Snow <tony@example.com>` and `(tony snow) tony@example.com`? What do you want to return from `tony%example.com@example.org` ? The current standard for the format of an email address is here: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt

Comment: If you need to parse complete email addresses, not just this simple form, you even more definitely don't want a regex. See [`email.utils.parseaddr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parseaddr) in the std lib and friends, or search for third-party libraries on PyPI if for some reason this isn't appropriate. Getting all of the details right is very hard. And this is exactly why python comes with batteries included.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should just use the [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method of strings:

```
s.split("@")[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, the better solution is to use `split`.

If you're really keen on using `regex` then this should work:

```
import re

regexStr = r'^([^@]+)@[^@]+$'
emailStr = 'foo@bar.baz'
matchobj = re.search(regexStr, emailStr)
if not matchobj is None:
    print matchobj.group(1)
else:
    print "Did not match"
```

and it prints out

```
foo
```

**NOTE:** This is going to work only with email strings of `SOMEONE@SOMETHING.TLD`. If you want to match emails of type `NAME<SOMEONE@SOMETHING.TLD>`, you need to adjust the regex.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use right RFC5322 parser.

`"@@@@@"@example.com` is a valid email address, and semantically localpart(`"@@@@@"`) is different from its username(`@@@@@`)

As of python3.6, you can use `email.headerregistry`:

```py
from email.headerregistry import Address

s='xjhgjg876896@domain.com'
Address(addr_spec=s).username # => 'xjhgjg876896'
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use a regex or `split`.

```
local, at, domain = 'john.smith@example.org'.rpartition('@')
```

Comment: The question was only to get the first part of the email address. So it would be better ``prefix, _, _ = 'john.smith@example.org'.rpartition('@')``.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way, using the index method.

```
s='xjhgjg876896@domain.com'

# Now lets find the location of the "@" sign
index = s.index("@")

# Next lets get the string starting from the begining up to the location of the "@" sign.
s_id = s[:index]

print(s_id)
```

And the output is

```
xjhgjg876896
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6


def email_splitter(email):
    username = email.split('@')[0]
    domain = email.split('@')[1]
    domain_name = domain.split('.')[0]
    domain_type = domain.split('.')[1]

    print('Username : ', username)
    print('Domain   : ', domain_name)
    print('Type     : ', domain_type)


email_splitter('foo.goo@bar.com')
```

Output :

```
Username :  foo.goo
Domain   :  bar
Type     :  com
```

Comment: this would fail for  `foo.goo@here.domain.com`

Answer (score 1):

need to install package
pip install email_split

```
from email_split import email_split
email = email_split("ssss@ggh.com")
print(email.domain)
print(email.local)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should help you do it :

```
 fromAddr = message.get('From').split('@')[1].rstrip('>')
        fromAddr = fromAddr.split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Good answers have already been answered but i want to put mine anyways.

- If i have an email john@gmail.com i want to get just "john".

  > i want to get only "john"
- If i have an email john.joe@gmail.com i want to get just "john"

  > i want to get only "john"

so this is what i did:

```
name = recipient.split("@")[0]
name = name.split(".")[0]
print name
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use email_split.

```
from email_split import email_split
email = email_split('xjhgjg876896@domain.com')
email.local  # xjhgjg876896
email.domain  # domain.com
```

You can find more here https://pypi.org/project/email_split/ . Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will return the continuous text before @

```
 re.findall(r'(\S+)@', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

split() is an elegant option, but if asked to use REGEX, utilizing **grouping** to capture the part before @ is quite straightforward.

the example below captures the name part which contains a-z,A-Z,0-9 only. Grouping is achieved by using **( )** around that part of regex, i.e. ***([a-zA-Z0-9]+)***.

```
import re
regex_email = r"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@\S+"
s1 = "This is my email: hello@world.com"
print(re.findall(regex_email, s1)) 

#output is ['hello']
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```
def get_email_name(self, email):
    return self.email.split("@")[0]

def get_email_domain(self, email):
    return self.email.split("@")[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find all the words in the email and then return the first word.

```
import re
def returnUserName(email):
    return re.findall("\w*",email)[0]

print(returnUserName("johns123.ss@google.com"))   #Output is - johns123
print(returnUserName('xjhgjg876896@domain.com'))  #Output is - xjhgjg876896
```